Subset rows using slice_max() - how to use it in R?
I have to create a partial data set containing only the 20 days with the highest daily mean air temperature values for each year. My dataset looks like this:



date
mean




1997-07-15
27.05292


1997-07-17
26.86542


1997-06-21
26.10958


1997-07-16
26.05833


1997-07-14
26.02500


1997-06-25
25.80125


1997-07-18
25.36208


1997-06-22
25.18875


1997-06-29
24.72333


1997-06-30
24.71000



...
I tried to use the code bellow, but this one only filters the maximum from every year and creates a dataframe with 20 rows - but I need the Top 20 mean values from every year (1997 – 2010). I use the class data.frame btw. I would be so grateful if anyone can help me, I just can't figure it out!
top_20_per_year <- daily_mean_temp_sorted %>%
  slice_max(mean, n = 20) %>%


Hi - when you invoke any function not in the base package, be sure to identify the package (library) it belongs to.

Example taking the top 2 mean values by year:
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~date, ~mean,
  "1997-07-15", 27.05292,
  "1997-07-17", 26.86542,
  "1997-06-21", 26.10958,
  "1997-07-16", 26.05833,
  "1997-07-14", 26.02500,
  "1998-06-25", 25.80125,
  "1998-07-18", 25.36208,
  "1998-06-22", 25.18875,
  "1998-06-29", 24.72333,
  "1998-06-30", 24.71000
)

df |> 
  mutate(date = ymd(date), year = year(date)) |> 
  slice_max(n = 2, order_by = mean, by = year)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   date        mean  year
#>   <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1997-07-15  27.1  1997
#> 2 1997-07-17  26.9  1997
#> 3 1998-06-25  25.8  1998
#> 4 1998-07-18  25.4  1998

Created on 2024-04-29 with reprex v2.1.0

oh, you beat me by a few seconds... The by argument is quite handy. I was not aware of it,  but it is also worth noting that is an experimental feature and might be changed or dropped in future releases...

Yes, I have a feeling it will stick as temporary grouping is embedded in many functions now, e.g. mutate, summarise etc. :)  I find it very handy rather than 3 lines to group_by, do something, then ungroup ... which remains very useful in certain circumstances.

The following should do.
library(dplyr) # load dplyr

# example data set
n <- 100
daily_mean_temp_sorted <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(seq(from=1, to=1000, length.out=n)),
  mean = runif(n=n)
)

# group by year and slice
top_20_per_year <- daily_mean_temp_sorted |> 
  group_by(year = as.numeric(format(date, "%Y"))) |> 
  slice_max(mean, n = 20) 
  

